# How to clear the Info message appearing on the Lookup popup window

Tags: lookup, pagemessages

[image]

As we can see in the above image, when user is trying to selecting a lookup record, I have this page message appearing on the lookup window.

I am confused on how to debug this. Searched the whole source folder but could not find anything.

**Note:** This is not a custom lookup window but the regular salesforce feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message comes from the Filter lookup as shown below.

[image]

For example if you have contact lookup on Opportunity. go to that field from Opportunity-> Fields-> Edit Lookup field name and update the message.